How can i enable Token_IDs in the new Azure/Microsoft Entra interface
When i try to log in to an application via Azure SSO, the below error is returned:
AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application.

There are resources online on how to rectify this, such as here and here but all the screenshots are of the old interface. The new interface does not have a checkbox for Token IDs:

Any ideas on how to fix using the new interface?

To enable ID Token in the new Microsoft Entra interface, you need update below property to true in Manifest of your app registration:
{
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
}


When I checked the same in Authentication tab after saving the update, ID Token enabled successfully like this:

